Testing logs in Rust
How to properly initialize a logger in Rust unit tests to avoid conflicts?
I'm writing unit tests in Rust that verify log outputs. Each test passes individually, but when I run all tests together with cargo test, it fails because the logger is initialized multiple times. Here is a simplified version of one of my tests:
fn test_warn_update_node_in_empty_tree(
    #[case] root_index: NodeIndex,
    #[case] leaf_indices: &[NodeIndex],
    #[case] expected_logs: usize,
    #[case] mut update_skeleton: UpdatedSkeletonTreeImpl,
) {
    let mut test_logger = Logger::start();
    update_skeleton.update_node_in_empty_tree(&root_index, leaf_indices);
    let logs = test_logger.pop();
    let warn_logs: Vec<_> = logs
        .iter()
        .filter(|record| record.level() == Level::Warn)
        .collect();
    assert_eq!(warn_logs.len(), expected_logs);
}


By default, tests are run in parallel.  Presumably your code has some global state that is not expecting that.  You can instead run tests sequentially by passing --test-threads=1 to the test runner.  But perhaps you can also fix your code so that it supports parallel tests: however you'd need to provide more detail than you have here, eg a [mcve].

If you're using tracing there's the tracing-test crate to help with that. Tracing can also absorb logs from log but I haven't checked if that works in unit tests.

Init your logger in before code and use https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html
